# Inserting months and updating it with Amount

Tags: php, mysql

I have no idea, how I need to do this and will be grateful if anyone can help.

first, if a customer says she would pay a certain amount in 5 months, I want to be able to insert the months with the amount to be paid for each month.

Eg Five months from September and the amount is 30 per month. So I should be able to insert soothing like the table1 into mysql database. I am using php

table1

```html
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="30" valign="top"><p>#</p></td>
    <td width="138" valign="top"><p>date</p></td>
    <td width="126" valign="top"><p>Amount</p></td>
    <td width="72" valign="top"><p>Status</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="30" valign="top"><p>1</p></td>
    <td width="138" valign="top"><p>01/10/2015</p></td>
    <td width="126" valign="top"><p>30</p></td>
    <td width="72" valign="top"><p>unpaid</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="30" valign="top"><p>2</p></td>
    <td width="138" valign="top"><p>01/11/2015</p></td>
    <td width="126" valign="top"><p>30</p></td>
    <td width="72" valign="top"><p>unpaid</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="30" valign="top"><p>3</p></td>
    <td width="138" valign="top"><p>01/12/2015</p></td>
    <td width="126" valign="top"><p>30</p></td>
    <td width="72" valign="top"><p>unpaid</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="30" valign="top"><p>4</p></td>
    <td width="138" valign="top"><p>01/01/2016</p></td>
    <td width="126" valign="top"><p>30</p></td>
    <td width="72" valign="top"><p>unpaid</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="30" valign="top"><p>5</p></td>
    <td width="138" valign="top"><p>01/02/2016</p></td>
    <td width="126" valign="top"><p>30</p></td>
    <td width="72" valign="top"><p>unpaid</p></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

For this table I do not know how to insert the date for next five months starting from October.

Then the second challenge is if she comes in to pay say 65 I should be able to update the table spreading the 65 over three months as

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="30" valign="top"><p>#</p></td>
    <td width="138" valign="top"><p>date</p></td>
    <td width="126" valign="top"><p>Amount Due</p></td>
    <td width="72" valign="top"><p>Status</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="30" valign="top"><p>1</p></td>
    <td width="138" valign="top"><p>01/10/2015</p></td>
    <td width="126" valign="top"><p>30</p></td>
    <td width="72" valign="top"><p>Paid</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="30" valign="top"><p>2</p></td>
    <td width="138" valign="top"><p>01/11/2015</p></td>
    <td width="126" valign="top"><p>30</p></td>
    <td width="72" valign="top"><p>Paid</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="30" valign="top"><p>3</p></td>
    <td width="138" valign="top"><p>01/12/2015</p></td>
    <td width="126" valign="top"><p>25</p></td>
    <td width="72" valign="top"><p>Unpaid</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="30" valign="top"><p>4</p></td>
    <td width="138" valign="top"><p>01/01/2016</p></td>
    <td width="126" valign="top"><p>30</p></td>
    <td width="72" valign="top"><p>Unpaid</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="30" valign="top"><p>5</p></td>
    <td width="138" valign="top"><p>01/02/2016</p></td>
    <td width="126" valign="top"><p>30</p></td>
    <td width="72" valign="top"><p>Unpaid</p></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: So what exactly did you try yourself? What is your question? What is it you expect from us? Please don't say you have no idea how to do it and want us to write a completely functional database and script to handle this. Even IF someone is nice enough to do it, it would become a complete book to answer your question.

Comment: Sorry about that. what i tried was to insert the month and the amount as and when she makes payment but the problem i had with that is sometimes she may pay more that is required for a particular month. In that case the the excess amount has to go to the month. that is basically where the issue is. it dealing with the excess amount in particular i meant i had no idea about.

Comment: May be i will have revise my question, breaking it up so it becomes understandable

Comment: I would simply make 2 columns. One with the amount that has to be paid, and one with the amount that is already paid. Next you can simply substract one from the other and devide the remain amount over the upcoming months, or simply use a modulo to divide 30 over each remaining month and set the modulo value for the next upcoming one.

Comment: That's nice of you. You have given me something to start with. Thank you. I will let you know the outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example script on how to do it as I explained in the comments before. All you have to do is adept your database and output to it:

```
<?php

$costs = 180; //Total costs
$month_costs = 30; //Costs per month
$paid = 80; //Paid first & second month + 10 dollar / euro extra
$months = $costs / $month_costs; //Total months

//Substract amount paid from total costs
$remaining_costs = $costs - $paid;

//Get the modulo value - This will be how much is remaining for
//the first month that isn't fully paid yet
$mod = $remaining_costs % $month_costs;

//Get the remaining months
$remaining_months = $remaining_costs / $month_costs;

//Floor the remaining months
//So if $remaining_months = 2.354 etc, it becomes 2
$floored_months = floor($remaining_months);

//Substract the floored value from $months
$open_months = $months - $floored_months;

//Echo out what is paid
for($i=1;$i<$months;$i++){
    if($open_months > $i){
        echo "Month ". $i .": paid.<br />";
    } else {
        break;
    }
}

//Echo out last month paid if fully paid
if($open_months >= $months){
    echo "Month ". $i .": paid.<br />";
}

//Echo out the amount remaining for next month if there's still something open:
if($remaining_costs > 0 && $mod != 0){
    echo "Month ". $i .": $". $mod ." remaining.<br />"; //$mod will return 10 because 2 x 30 and 1 x 20 was paid
} else {
    echo "Month ". $i .": paid.<br />";
}

//Echo out the remaining months if there are any:
if($i < $months){

    //Update $i
    $i++;

    //Echo out the remaining months:
    for($y=$i;$y<=$months;$y++){
        echo "Month ". $y .": $". $month_costs ." remaining.<br />";
    }
}

//Echo out if there's to much paid:
if($paid > $costs){
    $toMuch = $paid - $costs;
    echo "You have paid ". $toMuch ." to much.";
}

?>
```

Result:

> Month 1: paid.
>  Month 2: paid.
>  Month 3: $10 remaining.
>   Month 4: $30 remaining.
>  Month 5: $30 remaining.
>  Month 6:
>   $30 remaining.